# Visual Studio licensing questions?

Tags: discussion, licensing

Which of the following sites in the **Stack Overflow Trilogy** would be the best for asking questions about Visual Studio licensing costs?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdnsubscriptions

Comment: @Ian Ringrose...thanks for providing an comment to back up Jay Riggs answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO

Comment: Could someone explain me, why this is the accepted answer?

Comment: Ouch!  When I first wrote it it got a couple upvotes and this was when it was accepted.  Since then it's been hammered.  I'd like to delete it but because it's an accepted answer I can't, and it doesn't seem right to me to change it (maybe I'm wrong about that).  I see the OP hasn't logged on in a while and when he does perhaps he'll let me put it out of its misery!

Comment: Since this is meta.stackoverflow.com, a site to ask questions about SO, SF, and SU, I wanted to know which of these three sites would be the best place to inquire information about people's experience with VS licensing.  It would be quite obvious that Microsoft would be the first place I would check before coming here.  @Jay Riggs...no idea why you would get the stinkvote from everyone.

Comment: @Michael:  You could ask on SO, but the company (Microsoft) would be the best place to find information.  It is after all their software and their licensing rules. They could inform you best of your options (lots of them in this case) of their licensing conditions.

Comment: It's the right answer to the question as asked.  Assuming the information on Microsoft's site was insufficient, and the questioner wanted our opinion on the interpretation, SO is the correct place.

Comment: @David: As you can see by counting the votes to the answers of this question, I would assume that a question about licensing gets closed pretty fast on SO. I.e. it is not the correct place. You don't get any answer.

Answer (score 11):

http://microsoft.com.

Comment: This. Why on earth would anyone go anywhere *non-authoritative* with such questions?

Comment: Have you ever tried to understand MS' licensing model?

Comment: @voyager: why would you even *say* such a thing?! You don't try to *understand* such abominations, you don't even *speak of them by name* unless forced, and then only in whispered tones... To attempt to understand them would be to welcome madness, to throw wide the doors of your soul and invite in the screeching demon horde. Understand them? No, my friend, *a thousand times no*! Recognize and accept that there is evil and discord in this world, but for the love of all that is good and holy **DO NOT** attempt to understand it...

Comment: @Shog9: So MS is Cthulu? Somehow I had my suspicions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a start-up or contractor etc you will find that StackOverflow gives you the best answers, otherwise you need to talk to a Microsoft reseller.    However the Microsoft resellers will not tell you about the schemes that Microsoft has in place for start-ups.

Answer (score 1):

Your local [Microsoft Partner](https://partner.microsoft.com) is actually the best resource. Failing that, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26859/visual-studio-licensing-questions/26861#26861).

Comment: I've tried that. Their reps are as confused as the rest of us about how their insanely complicated licensing program works.

Comment: @JohnFx: that means that they are close enough to humans.